# Plugin installation failed

Tags: php, opencart

What can be a problem with OpenCart because when I try to install a plugin I get:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /home/agroagro/public_html/open/admin/controller/multiseller/base.php on line 13
> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleMultiseller::$data has no effect in /home/agroagro/public_html/open/admin/controller/multiseller/base.php on line 14
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/agroagro/public_html/open/admin/index.php:84) in /home/agroagro/public_html/open/system/library/response.php on line 12

Anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error is from using an OpenCart 1.5 extension in OpenCart 2.0.  The two are not compatible.